# Aspx C#: How to get result of Eval(...) in grid_HtmlRowCreated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

I'm trying to use a parameter from .aspx in C# code inside grid_HtmlRowCreated method.
I tried it by setting a text in a label in .aspx and then fetch that text from the label.

It worked:
aspx

```
<dx:ASPxLabel runat="server"  ID="cl" Text="Some text"/>
```

...

```
protected void grid_HtmlRowCreated(object sender, ASPxGridViewTableRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowType == DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.GridViewRowType.Data)
        {
                   ...
            string id;

            if (comments_grid != null && expIDControl != null)
            {
                id = ((DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxLabel)expIDControl).Text;      
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show( id );
            }
    }
```

But when I set the value like:

```
<dx:ASPxLabel runat="server"  ID="cl" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'/>
```

then id is empty and when I set

```
<dx:ASPxLabel runat="server"  ID="cl" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %> + " test"'/>
```

then id is literally <%# Eval("Id") %> test

Thank You for any ideas...

EDIT: That works as well, the code just need to be in HtmlRowPrepared, not in HtmlRowCreated. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a method on the class (.aspx.cs) that will concatenate.

Going from memory:

```
Text='<%# ConcatSomething (Eval("Id")  ,  "Peanut" ) %> '/>
```

and then

```
    public object ConcatSomething(object x , object y)
    {
        return Convert.ToString(x) + Convert.ToString(y);
    }
```

or maybe

```
    public object ConcatSomething(string x , string y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
```

You'll have to play with it.  I've done it a thousand times on data_binding.

The stinker is the "object" stuff.
And you'll have to code for null values (coming in) if you may have some.

Comment: I tried, but it's the same.
It seems like HtmlRowCreated collects text from Label before executing <%# ... %>

Comment: After the page is rendered (client side) what is one of the TextBox's value in the HTML?  Is that correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

I just copied this from my current project , I have the same Grid with Item template and the correct way to do it is :

```
<dx:ASPxLabel runat="server"  ID="cl" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>' />
```

regards

Comment: The same problem,
it generates correct value but it seems a bit too late